# Show that $Ln(i^{-i})\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-numbers

$z=e^{i\theta},i=\sqrt{-1}$,
$i^{-1}Ln(z)=\theta, \theta\in[0,2\pi)$.
Show that  $Ln(i^{-i})$ is a real number.

Comment: Just for fun, what is $i^{-i}$ exactly? I know no canonical definition of a function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$ sending $z$ to $z^{-i}$, do you?

Comment: "canonical function" Not mentioned in my comment.

Comment: This is surprising since your question requires to know what $i^{-i}$ is, that is, **how it is defined**, otherwise one can declare that $i^{-i}=42$ and consider the exercise solved since $\mathrm{Ln}(42)$ is a real number.

Comment: I feel like you are unable to explain key notions that are crucial to make sense of the question and that you are formulating some rather ridiculous accusations instead of providing any substance to the question. Again: **How do you define $i^{-i}$?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the principal branch:

$$\text{Log} \,i=\log|i|+i\arg i=0+i\frac\pi2=\frac{\pi i}2$$

so

$$i^{-i}=e^{-i\text{ Log}\,i}=e^{-i\cdot\frac{\pi i}2}=e^{\frac\pi2}\in\Bbb R$$

I just did the above for fun.

Answer (score 0):

$i=e^{\frac {\pi i}2+2k\pi i}$

$i^{-i}=e^{(\frac {\pi i}2+2k\pi i)(-i)}$

$i^{-i}=e^{\frac {\pi}2+2k\pi}$